# Как узнать запущен ли процесс

Tags: c#, процесс

Вот допустим у меня в процессах есть `calc` калькулятор. Как узнать с помощью C# существует ли он. Т.е если он существует `label1.text = "процесс существует";`, иначе `label1.text = "процесс не существует";`

Comment: >если он существует label1.text = "процесс существует";иначе label1.text = "процесс не существует";

мне даже в ТЗ таких подробностей не описывали

Comment: ну ты так поможешь?

Comment: С таким-то ником, а не можете даже погуглить.

Answer (score 9):

```
label1.text = Process.GetProcessesByName("calc").Any() ? "процесс существует" : "процесс не существует";
```

Впрочем, не знаю, что вы подразумеваете под "существует". Этот код показывает, запущен ли процесс с этим именем